# Can't edit a PDF in ai CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, image-editing

I converted a .tiff image into a .pdf.

I then opened that pdf in illustrator. I tried opening using File>open, File>place, or just the drag and drop. But none of these allows me to edit the pdf.

Before when I've opened a pdf in illustrator, the pdf automatically gets divided into lots of vectors and paths and I can edit the pdf. But for some reason, this pdf does not divide into individual selectable components.

I'm not sure what's going on. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to work on your understanding of graphic formats. (1) Converting a TIFF into a PDF does not make a vector out of a bitmap and magically make it 'editable'. (2) Illustrator is not a PDF editor. While it *may* successfully open *some* PDFs, it's by far not true that it will work for *any* and *all* PDF files.

Answer (score 2):

You can only edit the TIFF if that file was made with layers. Turning the TIFF into a PDF will not let you automatically edit parts of the graphic if that file is flattened.

Try opening the TIFF file in Illustrator. If a dialogue boxes opens, it will ask you if you want to open the file with layers.

[image: tiff options]